# Trigger to disable insert into a table for a specific day in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i correctly write a trigger for this task:

```
create or replace trigger M_t2
after insert on emp

begin

if ( to_char(sysdate,'DY' ) = 'TUE' ) then
    dbms_output.put_line('cannot insert into emp on tuesday');
end if;

end;
/
```

This does not work as i am still able to insert like this:

```
insert into emp(empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno) values('7935','BOLT','ANALYST',7698,sysdate,900,100,10);
```

Comment: A trigger using this: `to_char(sysdate,'DY' ) = 'TUE'` will not have any effect if the insert was initiated from my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbms_output` doesn't stop you doing anything, and you won't even see that message if your client isn't set up to show the output.

To prevent an action you'd need to raise an exception:

```
if ( to_char(sysdate,'DY' ) = 'TUE' ) then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'cannot insert into emp on tuesday');
end if;
```

The `DY` value is NLS-dependent so this could be circumvented by having a session with a different language, so you should take that into account using the [optional third parameter to `to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm). It might as well be a before-insert trigger too:

```
create or replace trigger M_t2
before insert on emp
begin
  if ( to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) = 'TUE' ) then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'cannot insert into emp on tuesday');
  end if;
end;
/

insert into emp ...

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: cannot insert into emp on tuesday
ORA-06512: at "<schema>.N_T2", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '<schema>.M_T2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php
I think you must use :new clause and use variable

Comment: Why do you think that? There's nothing wrong with testing `sysdate`?